# Would an LM7805 need a heatsink stepping down two stacked LiR2032/CR2032 (3.6V X2) batteries?

Tags: design, bluetooth, low-power, headphones, digital-audio

Okay, I'm terrible at anything electronic, especially when it comes to building from boards (think rudimentary understanding). I've built a few PC's in my day, but piecemeal, not from scratch. Keep that in mind; I'm a moron. Now, what I hope to accomplish is a Bluetooth bone conduction headset that I can hide in a standard baseball cap (to safely violate a work rule against listening to music).

So, here's the idea: I take a 5W x2 Stereo Audio Bluetooth 5.0 Digital Mini Amplifier Module DC 5V (this one to be exact:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08G8JTDVC/ref=sspa_dk_detail_2?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B08G8JTDVC&pd_rd_w=vrXZH&pf_rd_p=4269e1a0-a218-4fbd-9748-1cd337d2f2a5&pd_rd_wg=oj1xL&pf_rd_r=969K1JJJ90CHTFM4BN16&pd_rd_r=5fc163f0-574b-45a3-aa1f-94895fe8f16a&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExNllXOTlSRkdFWllVJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMDY3NDE5MVIzRFRGODE3QlVPMCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNzI0MTE4UEFFUkpRNUtTUEhCJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfZGV0YWlsJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08G8JTDVC)), connect two 20mm Piezo Discs in place of the speakers, and power it with the aforementioned LiR2032 x2 stack.

I'm going with LiR2032 because they're rechargeable, but if you think there's a better solution (maybe USB rechargeable integration or something), I'm definitely all ears, but, it needs to be small. The LM7805 would of course be between the battery stack and the Bluetooth amp board. Now, if that's the only problem, how much heat would be generated in the stepdown, and would I need a heatsink or a larger regulator?

Now, being as stupid as I am, I'm probably missing a WHOLE LOT of parts with this project, maths, and such that will ultimately doom this to short circuit at best and my death at worst. If anyone has a better idea on how to structure this, what I imagine your superior knowledge sees as an outright disaster, I'm all ears on that front too.

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: A pair of 2032s won't power a 5W amplifier so the question is moot.

Comment: The 7805 will flatten the cr2032s quickly anyways.

Comment: LiR2032 cells have a capacity of 70mAh. That's a whopping 210mWh each. Running a pair of them for an hour at a draw of 20mA will cause 20mWh to be consumed in the regulator. Running them for 3 and a half hours will see 70mWh of you 420mWh eaten there. That's 1/6th!! Rather than use a linear regulator, I'd look for an smd switch-mode one - it'll be much smaller and more efficient. I can buy 10 of the following converters for AUD $14 https://aliexpress.ru/item/32767090250.html?spm=a2g0v.12010612.8148356.2.521e4457X9s9vx&sku_id=62213087131

Comment: So, what would be a better power supply for the set up?